# How to migrate a complex project from Angular 1.5 to 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, jhipster

I have a production site with realtime data.

- The site is based on jHipster (angular 1.5 + java).
- The site is state based.
- Websockets are used for asynchronous communication.

Now, I want to migrate the site from angular v1.5 to v2. On reading the official angular migration guide, it seems I have to rewrite a lot of code. What is the best approach here for migration?

1. Write everything in angular 2 from scratch.

   or
2. Follow the upgrade guide (using the upgrade module) in the official angular doc

Comment: write it again from scratch. that always makes for a better codebase, even if it's rewritten in the same environ as the first time, you learned from your mistakes so the 2nd version is better.

Comment: Only you can decide that...try both approaches

Comment: Angular 2 is **VERY** different from Angular 1. I'm surprised that it even has an upgrade guide

Comment: Build a sample ang2 app first to get a taste... then build your old app from the ground up in ang2, will be miles quicker that a conversion.

Answer (score 0):

**It depends**.

Anyways, **you have to rewrite a lot of code**. That's for sure. And there is no easy way.

I will share with you two ideas (approaches), other then simply re-writing everything from the bottom up:

1. Using the `ngForward` approach.

   In the `ngForward` approach, we are not actually upgrading existing Angular 1.x applications — we are creating an environment where these 1.x applications will behave like Angular 2 applications. In other words, we can gradually rewrite our Angular 1.x app to work like an Angular 2 app. We can then further augment new Angular 2 features to this 1.x application on the top of the existing app.

   Find out more in [this blog post](http://www.codelord.net/2016/02/03/angular-2-migration-whats-ng-forward/).
2. Using the `ngUpgrade` approach.

   By using the `ngForward` approach, we can write the code in the Angular 2.0 way on top of the existing Angular 1.x applications. However, this approach may not be comfortable for some as concerns over its maintainability and backward compatibility with the future Angular versions could be an issue. The `ngForward` approach will definitely cause problems for bulky Angular 1.x applications in the long run. This problem has been nailed down to a large extent with the use of the `ngUpgrade` approach. The `ngUpgrade` approach has the comprehensive documentation which can be obtained from the [official Angular website](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html).

You need to make a decision based on your specific use-case, project objectives and etc.

Credits: I learned that from [this tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/angularjs/tutorial/migrating-from-angular-1-to-angular-2).

Answer (score 0):

There's a third approach as well: create the parallel code base in Angular 2 and link it with the old Angular 1x code via url navigations. Here you will not need to fix or change any LOC of previous code base except for adding new navigation URLs. This will save your time. Your new code will have pure Angular 2, without any mixes of 1.5 and 2x at the same time on a page. The only challenge is to share user state and data in between requests since you cannot use shared services or factories anymore, but this is doable.

My history of similar migrations has been recently published in [this blog post](http://www.diatomenterprises.com/migration-history-from-angularjs-1-3-to-1-5-and-then-2-0/).